# Invalid procedure call or argument error creating a pivot table in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded a macro creating a pivot table off of another table in excel VBA. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error: "Run time error '5'" invalid procedure call or argument."

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Table_FTE_Distributions4.24", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "'Sheet6'! R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=15
```

Comment: Once you made a pivot table, you cannot name he others "PivotTable1" too. You should change the name accordingly. Maybe position as well. But I guess position will not trigger an error but will cause a warning.

Comment: ^ also, what is `"Table_FTE_Distributions4.24"` ? `Named Range` ? `Table` (`ListObject`) ?

Comment: That's the name of the table I'm making the pivot off of.

Comment: @Michaela read my answer and test my code below, let me know if it works for you

Comment: @ShaiRado i renamed the pivot tables and it worked - thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to create "PivotTable1" in "Sheet6" in case it doesn't exist. If it'a already created (from past code runs) just update it with the updated `PivotCache`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub RefreshPivots()

Dim ShtPivot    As Worksheet
Dim PivTbl      As PivotTable
Dim PivCache    As PivotCache
Dim Tbl         As ListObject
Dim SrcRng      As Range

' set the Pivot Sheet
Set ShtPivot = Worksheets("Sheet6")

' set the ListObject to "Table_FTE_Distributions4.24"
Set Tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table_FTE_Distributions4.24")

' set the Pivot Caches SourceData
Set SrcRng = Tbl.Range

' set the Pivot Cache
Set PivCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcRng)

' add this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PivTbl = ShtPivot.PivotTables("PivotTable1") ' check if "PivotTable1" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PivTbl Is Nothing Then
    ' create a new Pivot Table in "Sheet6", start from Cell A3
    Set PivTbl = ShtPivot.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PivCache, TableDestination:=ShtPivot.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable1")

Else
     ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range in "Table_FTE_Distributions4.24"
    MsgBox "PivotTable1 already exists, onyl need to refresh the Pivot Cache"
    PivTbl.ChangePivotCache PivCache
    PivTbl.RefreshTable
End If

End Sub
```